# Accessing WebSocket handshake rejection headers

Tags: angularjs, node.js, websocket

I'm using [angular-websockets](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket) and [node websockets](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/), although that shouldn't make too much of a difference. The node implementation sends an `X-WebSocket-Reject-Reason` header with the handshake request rejection (e.g. "invalid username").

How would I access this header via the websockets API, or otherwise? I haven't explored this sufficiently, but it doesn't appear that `$httpProvider` can't intercept the request.

The `onError`, `onClose`, etc. callbacks don't help, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because the websocket API specification for browsers forbids it.
See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/#feedback-from-the-protocol

> User agents must not convey any failure information to scripts in a way that would allow a script to distinguish the following situations:
>
> ...
>
> A server that did not complete the opening handshake (e.g. because it was not a WebSocket server).

This means the browser is not allowed to pass the websocket handshakes HTTP response header to javascript due to security concerns.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I could accept the handshake, send an "invalid username" message, and then close the socket.